# BuildKite: Set environment variables for downstream steps

Tags: environment-variables, cicd, buildkite

I would like to export a job input parameters as environment variables to the subsequent steps.

According to the [documentation](https://buildkite.com/docs/agent/v3/cli-env#setting-a-jobs-environment-variables), I can use `env set`:

> `buildkite-agent env set [variable]`
>
> Sets environment variables in the current job execution environment.
> Changes to the job environment variables only apply to subsequent
> phases of the job.

However it does not seem to work.

Simplified example:

```
env:
    DEFAULT_FOO: a_foo

name: "Parametrized test"
steps:
- input: "Parameters"
  label: "Set parameters"
  key: "input-params"
  fields:
    - text: "Name of Foo"
      key: "foo_param"
      hint: "Example: Foo, foo, FOO, ..."
      required: true
      default: "${DEFAULT_FOO}"
- command: |
    echo FOO="$(buildkite-agent meta-data get foo_param)"
    buildkite-agent env set FOO="$(buildkite-agent meta-data get foo_param)"
    buildkite-agent pipeline upload .buildkite/pipeline.matrix.yml

  depends_on: "input-params"
  label: "Configure matrix pipeline"
```

I can see `meta-data get` works as expected. I.e. this line:

```
echo FOO="$(buildkite-agent meta-data get foo_param)"
```

Prints `FOO=<whatever value I set in input>`. As one would expect.

However this step fails:

```
buildkite-agent env set FOO="$(buildkite-agent meta-data get foo_param)"
```

With error:

```
Could not create Job API client: BUILDKITE_AGENT_JOB_API_SOCKET empty or undefined
This command can only be used from hooks or plugins running under a job executor
where the "job-api" experiment is enabled.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Is the documentation misleading?

Would also appreciate any suggestion for alternative ways to pass input parameters to downstream pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering with help from BK team on [this GH issue](https://github.com/buildkite/agent/issues/2233).

> Could not create Job API client: BUILDKITE_AGENT_JOB_API_SOCKET empty or undefined

This error is due to the (experimental) Job API being off by default.
To enable, add `experiment=job-api` in `buildkite-agent.conf`

**However, using the JOB API was the wrong approach for this problem.**

All I needed was an `export`, i.e.:

```
export echo FOO="$(buildkite-agent meta-data get foo_param)"
```

In the same step, I can reference and use FOO, but needs to be double-escaped, i.e.:

```
echo "The value of FOO is $$FOO"
```

But in subsequent steps (loaded from `.buildkite/pipeline.matrix.yml` in my case), there's no need to double-escape. i.e.:

```
echo "The value of FOO is $FOO"
```